# Eclipse color theme and non-editor area

Tags: eclipse, colors

I've installed the color theme and picked a dark style. However, all of the non-editor area (package view, etc.) is still bright and seems to distract due to the brightness.

Can you think of a way to remedy this problem? Maybe just make it darker or is there a way to extend the color setting to all of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one out:
https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes